# Negotiate arrays inside an array

Tags: php, html, css, arrays

When i perform a regular expression

```
preg_match_all('~(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)~', $content, $turls);
print_r($turls);
```

i got an array inside array. I need a single array only.

How to negotiate the arrays inside another arrays

Comment: What does your `print_r($turls)` print?

Comment: $content is actually file_get_contents("http://www.yahoo.com"); and so preg_match_all extracts the links from the yahoo.com and it is stored in the array $turls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default preg_match_all() uses PREG_PATTERN_ORDER flag, which means:

> Orders results so that $matches[0]  is
>   an array of full pattern matches,
>   $matches[1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389958/r-hill)  is an array of strings
>   matched by the first parenthesized
>   subpattern, and so on.

See http://php.net/preg_match_all

Here is sample output:

```
array(
    0 => array( // Full pattern matches
       0 => 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd',
       1 => ...
    ),

    1 => array( // First parenthesized subpattern.
                // In your case it is the same as full pattern, because first
                // parenthesized subpattern includes all pattern :-)
       0 => 'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd',
       1 => ...
    ),

    2 => array( // Second parenthesized subpattern.
       0 => 'www.w3.org',
       1 => ...
    ),
    ...
)
```

So, as [R. Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389958/r-hill) answered, you need $matches[0] to access all matched urls.
And as [budinov.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/377947/budinov-com) pointed, you should remove outer parentheses to avoid second match duplicate first one, e.g.:

```
preg_match_all('~https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?~', $content, $turls);
// where $turls[0] is what you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'negociate'. If you mean fetch the inner array, that should work:

```
$urls = preg_match_all('~(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)~', $content, $matches) ? $matches[0] : array();
if ( count($urls) ) {
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can replace your regexp with one that doesn't contain parenthesis (). This way your results will be hold just in the $turls[0] variable :

```
preg_match_all('/https?\:\/\/[^\"\'\s]+/i', file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com'), $turls);
```

and then do some code to make urls unique like this:

```
$result = array_keys(array_flip($turls[0]));
```